# Matrix vector multiplication optimisation - Cache size

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, matrix

This question is about C++ optimisation techniques. I have a matrix-vector multiplication with large dimensions and would like to reduce the runtime. I know that there are specialised libraries for linear algebra stuff, but I would actually like to learn a bit about the underlying processor peculiarities. So far, I am compiling with \O2 (Microsoft) and I got the compiler to confirm that the inner loop of the multiplication is vectorised.

The example code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

#define VEC_LENGTH 64
#define ITERATIONS 4000000

void gen_vector_matrix_multiplication(double *vec_result, double *vec_a, double *matrix_B, unsigned int cols_B, unsigned int rows_B)
{
    // initialise result vector
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows_B; i++)
    {
        vec_result[i] = 0;
    }
    // perform multiplication
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols_B; j++)
    {
        const double entry = vec_a[j];
        const int col = j*rows_B;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows_B; i++)
        {
            vec_result[i] += entry * matrix_B[i + col];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    double *vec_a = new double[VEC_LENGTH];
    double *vec_result = new double[VEC_LENGTH];
    double *matrix_B = new double[VEC_LENGTH*VEC_LENGTH];

    // start clock
    clock_t begin = clock();

    // this outer loop is just for test purposes so that the timing becomes meaningful
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++)
    {
        gen_vector_matrix_multiplication(vec_result, vec_a, matrix_B, VEC_LENGTH, VEC_LENGTH);
    }

    // stop clock
    double elapsed_time = static_cast<double>(clock() - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << elapsed_time/(VEC_LENGTH*VEC_LENGTH) << std::endl;

    delete[] vec_a;
    delete[] vec_result;
    delete[] matrix_B;

    return 1;
}
```

The multiplication is done several times to get a reliable estimate of the runtime. I have measured the runtime for a number of different vector length (in this example there is only one number of elements `N`, which is the length of the vector and at the same time defines the size of the matrix `NxN`) and normalised the measured runtime to the number of elements.

[image]

You can see that for small enough `N`, the run-time per operation is constant. However, above `N=512` the runtime jumps up. The difference between blue and red data points is the load on the processor. If the example program is running pretty much alone, the runtime is given by the blue dots and when the other cores are busy, the time is represented by the red dots.

I now have a couple of questions related to this.

- Am I correct in assuming that the jump between `N=512` and `N=1024`, is related to the size of the L3 cache of my processor (Ivy Bridge i5-3570) which should be 6MB? `512*512*8byte` equals roughly 2MB and `1024*1024*8byte` is roughly 8MB. So that the matrix does not fit into the cache any more and thus fetching data from RAM is the reason for the longer execution time?
- What is the reason behind the steady increase in runtime above this threshold?
- Any thoughts on the reason for the curves of busy and idle processor being so different above the threshold?
- What would be logical next steps in optimising this multiplication routine for operation with `N>1024`?

I am curious to hear your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: @tobi303 are you sure about the complexity? This is vector-matrix multiplication and not matrix-matrix. There only N*N operations.

Comment: ups, sorry must have missed this piece of information ;)

Comment: It might encourage the optimiser to declare vector_a and matrix_b as const double*. If you were using C I'd recommend using 'restrict' as well;  this is not C++ though some compilers -- eg gcc -- implement a form of it as an extension.

Comment: @dmuir Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried, but the times are essentially the same.

Comment: Strangely, this only auto-vectorizes with gcc/clang if your loop counters are signed.  With unsigned loop counters, maybe `i + col` could wrap, making the load not contiguous?  icc13 does auto-vectorize your original, but gcc and clang only do scalar double operations like `mulsd`.  [here's my version that does autovectorize](https://godbolt.org/g/1MS4pH).  Note that `-ffast-math` isn't required for it to vectorize, because vector*matrix is stuck in the awkward position of looping many times over the result vector, or doing strided loads from the matrix.  Prob. not worth inverting, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your comment! Yes, strange with the signed counters. I just tried to parallelise the inner loop and now the Microsoft compiler also required me to change to signed counters and bounds. It works now and the performance is a bit better for the largest N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normalization, I chose

```
elapsed_time/(VEC_LENGTH*VEC_LENGTH*ITERATIONS)
```

and it started with 6 nanoseconds and ended with 7 nanoseconds from N=64 to N=8192 where

```
ITERATIONS=20
```

and only cached thing for all cases is "vec_a" so only matrix elements are read from memory for large matrices.

Memory bandwidth is around 20 GB/s which means more than 2 G doubles per second. 
Core frequency is 3.7 GHz so this would be 3.7 G multiplications at max.

Core can issue 3.7 G doubles per second but memory feeds 2 G per second meaning.

Of course this is only for 64-bit fp operation. There is also

```
 i + col
```

that must be done before multiplication so this is a serial execution. 2 instructions at 3.7 GHz means nearly 1.8 G / second effectively. Close to 2.
Even if cache does its job, cpu core lacks compute power for this serial code.

Same thing happened when unrolled the loop by 4. This reduced time to half!. Now it is 3.4 nanoseconds per operation but for all N values because there is still 2 instuctions(1 integer and 1 floating point) after 1 unit of memory bandwidth that cpu must do.

**Edit:** Using all cores would surpass memory bandwidth and make effect of L3 cache more discernable.

Comment: That is interesting. Thank you very much! Strange that you measure a nearly constant time per iteration. I tried unrolling the loop by 4 as well, now the runtimes for all N are also nearly constant, however on the level of large N...

Comment: Try using all cores  to get past RAM bandwidth and unleash L3 cache advantage.

Comment: Yeah I just tried with the inner loop parallelised and I get an improvement of about 20% for the largest N. Below N=8192, the overhead of the parallelisation actually increases the runtime.

Comment: Parallelizing outer loop would be more efficient and more cache friendly because cores share all of the vector now. But that would need local accumulators to be added to get total sum of i-th element for destination vector.

Answer (score 2):

An important aspect of optimizing such codes is taking care of aliasing and vectorization, and your post suggests that you already took care of the latter. Quite often the compiler needs a bit of help. On GCC 5.3.0 the runtime reduces considerably using the loop below. The `__restrict__` qualifier tells the compiler that there is no aliasing possible, the `#pragma GCC ivdep` tells the GCC compiler that it is OK to vectorize the code. Furthermore, the compiler flags are extremely important as well. I compiled the code using `g++ -O3 -march=native -mtune=native matrix_example.cxx`.

```
void gen_vector_matrix_multiplication(double* const __restrict__ vec_result,
                                      const double* const __restrict__ vec_a,
                                      const double* const __restrict__ matrix_B,
                                      const int cols_B,
                                      const int rows_B)
{
    // initialise result vector
#pragma GCC ivdep
    for (int i = 0; i < rows_B; i++)
        vec_result[i] = 0;

    // perform multiplication
    for (int j = 0; j < cols_B; j++)
    {
        const double entry = vec_a[j];
        const int col = j*rows_B;

#pragma GCC ivdep
        for (int i = 0; i < rows_B; i++)
        {
            vec_result[i] += entry * matrix_B[i + col];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very for your answer! You are right, vectorisation helped a lot (but yes, the data I have shown in the question is already using a vectorise loop). The aliasing hint was good. I found some interesting things to read. But somehow using the restrict qualifier did not improve the situation in my specific case.

Comment: @AlexanderBüse, check what is the restrict qualifier for your compiler. Intel uses `restrict`, gcc and clang `__restrict__` and microsoft uses `__restrict` if I remember well.

Comment: Yes you are right it is `__restrict`, but unfortunately that did not improve the runtime.

Comment: @AlexanderBüse If you have checked that it is vectorized, I guess there is nothing more to gain.

Comment: Yeah, probably. Thanks for your help!